# jspdf-autotables listing all options within select (instead of just whats selected)

Tags: javascript, jspdf

```
function addWorkDetailsTopdf(pdf){
                    var tables =  document.querySelectorAll('.pbBody, table');
                    var res = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(tables[8]);
                    pdf.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
                                        startY: pdf.autoTableEndPosY()+10,
                                        tableWidth: 'wrap',
                                        styles: {cellPadding: 2},
                                        headerStyles: {rowHeight: 15, fontSize: 8},
                                        bodyStyles: {rowHeight: 12, fontSize: 8, valign: 'middle'}
                                                         });
                    return pdf;
                }
```

There are a few more items added to the pdf but eventually save is called.  The problem is that a drop down in one of the tables list out all available items rather than just the one selected.

[image]

In the image above Cleanup (or any other single item was selected) but it list all items (as stated above).

Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: Had your problem been solved ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70845404/js-pdf-autotable-generate-pdf-listing-all-options-tags-values-instead-of-just-s   Would you answer me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually edited a few things, definitely not an elegant solution.
There is a span above the select which houses the value for the selected item.  I manually edited the `res.data` to only have the value I needed

```
function addWorkDetailsTopdf(pdf){
                    var tables =  document.querySelectorAll('.pbBody, table');
                    var res = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(tables[8]);
                    var serviceType = res.data[0][1];
                    serviceType = serviceType.substr(0, serviceType.indexOf('--'));
                    if(serviceType === ""){
                        serviceType = 'None';
                        }
                    res.data[0][1] = serviceType;
                    pdf.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
                                        startY: pdf.autoTableEndPosY()+10,
                                        tableWidth: 'wrap',
                                        styles: {cellPadding: 2},
                                        headerStyles: {rowHeight: 15, fontSize: 8},
                                        bodyStyles: {rowHeight: 12, fontSize: 8, valign: 'middle'}
                                                         });
                    return pdf;
                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70845404/js-pdf-autotable-generate-pdf-listing-all-options-tags-values-instead-of-just-s   Would you answer me please?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same issue, i just added one line of code inside the plugin as followed:
in the function "parseContentCell" i added:

```
    if (cell.getElementsByTagName('select').length > 0) { return cell.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].options[cell.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].selectedIndex].text}
```

Comment: What is cell here?