# JS-pdf Autotable, generate pdf listing all options tags values instead of just selected tag, why?

Tags: jquery, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Mytable is like

```
<table class="table align-middle table-row-dashed fs-6 gy-5" id="kt_table_users">
<tr>
<th class="min-w-150px">Date</th>
<th class="min-w-125px">Name</th>
<th class="min-w-125px">Demo Course Enrolled</th>
<th class="min-w-300px">Product</th>
<th class="min-w-300px">Remarks</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<select class="products form-select form-select-solid" data-control="select2"
data-placeholder="Select an option" >
<option value="7" data-select2-id="select2-data-12-7357">Membership</option>
<option value="8" data-select2-id="select2-data-31-uhma">Math Block</option>
<option value="9" data-select2-id="select2-data-32-9h34">Academy</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

My JSPDF code

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4');
doc.autoTable({
html: '#kt_table_users',
showHead: "firstPage",
})
doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
```

[image]

These **MembershipMath
BlockAcademyIELTSNoor El
BayanDatascienceSCADACyber
DefenseCODSOffensive
PentestingDF/THMembership** all are option tag values, what should i do?